# Use Value From List To Set Variable Interactively

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've been searching for awhile, and I'm sure someone has to have asked this question before me, but I think I'm not using the correct search term (*not sure what to call this*).

I have a directory with sql files and I want to list the directory and assign each file a number value that the user then selects and that sets a variable with that file name so that I can use it to pass to a sql execute function. I mocked up the code below to show what I'm thinking in my head.

```
import os

upgrades =  os.listdir('upgrades')

select = 1

print '\nPlease select your upgrade: \n'

for sql in upgrades:
    print '['+str(select)+']: '+sql
    select +=1

print '\n'

selection = raw_input('-->')
```

Comment: You should use a dictionary, for preserving the names as the key and file names and the value.

Comment: Is there a function/method that does that uses a dict, instead of list for the OS module?

Comment: you've only gone part way here. can you post a complete best attempt that an answerer could then correct/improve?

Comment: No you have to do it by yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `upgrades` is a list, you can just index into it. Because you start with `1` and the list index starts with `0` just do:

```
selection = int(raw_input('-->'))
selected_sql = upgrades[selection - 1]
```

Comment: Thank you, I guess I just had a blank moment, that is a perfect and simple solution!